# Apache override in sub-location

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, webdav

This is my Apache vHost-configuration:

```
<VirtualHost subversion.domain.com:80>
    ServerAdmin changed@domain.com
    ServerName servername.domain.com

    Documentroot /srv/www/htdocs/svn

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/subversion-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/subversion-access_log combined


    HostnameLookups Off

    UseCanonicalName Off

    ServerSignature Off

    <Location "/">
            AuthBasicProvider ldap
            AuthType Basic
            AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
            AuthName "SVN"
            AuthLDAPURL "ldap://myldapurl/..." NONE
            AuthLDAPBindDN "mybinddn"
            AuthLDAPBindPassword mypwd
            DAV svn
            SVNParentPath /svn/
            SVNListParentPath on

            require ldap-group groupname

            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works perfectly. But I would now like to add a web-frontend for the subversion server. I therefore added the lines

```
    <Location "/web">
            DAV off
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
```

But they don't work, as the `<Location "/">...</Location>` part is directing the requests to the SVN/DAV module. Therefore, apache tells that it couldn't open the requested SVN-filsystem.

Does anybody know how to override this setting? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: exactly what kind of front end are you looking for? there is already a usable frontend to svn provided by collabnet. Is this a custom webpage you want to display in front of the source browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can not.** AFAIK, bug already filled to Apache (can't recall URL from topic somewhere in the SE, saw some days ago accidentally)

Comment: thank you for your reply. Okay... Maybe I can modify the question: can I change the part `<Location "/">...</Location>` to an expression like "everything except '/web' " ?

Comment: @Atmocreations - no, LocationMatch (which you imply) namely was mentioned as non-functional in relation to mod_dav

Comment: Ah... means this is a DAV-problem? What about to move the svn/dav-part to `<Location /svn>` and then create a proxy which redirects `/` to `/svn`. Would this work? If yes, what's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: proxy is overkill and *may affect* svn commands, which will produce 301 error on / access. Maybe /svn (or any other location at the same level as web) will be better? Not nice URL, but less headache

Comment: @Atmocreations - some links, probably related to dicussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665799/locationmatch-and-dav-svn + https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35077 (see at report-date)